# node.js 100% cpu utilization when running StatsD

Tags: performance, node.js, cpu-usage, metrics, statsd

I've wanted to test StatsD perfromance with some stress test which I've made.
Eventually I found out that when there are something like 80,000 packets per sec the Node.js is getting to 100% cpu utilization on my environment.

I know that 80,000 event per sec is quite huge amount of events , but I wonder if anyone knows what are the limits of StatsD in regarding to Node.js. What is a normal events rate?

Also, is there something I can do to imporve Node.js performance so it won't get to 100% cpu utilization?

Comment: You should share the code/results of the test, so that we can analyze that.

Comment: If you post the code, we may recommend some improvements to it.

Comment: This is StatsD relevant code https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/stats.js : basically it listens for UDP requests and handle it.

Comment: Actually I don't think it can be handled somehow, it is probably the limit of the Node.js on my specific environment. However, it is interesting to understand what are the limits of the events rate of StatsD on Node.js

Comment: One way to deal with it is to aggregate the events within the Node process and send the aggregated metrics every second/minute/hour depending on the metric type. That's how http://nodetime.com does it, for example.

Comment: By the way, notice that if I ran the same test via some other implementation of StatsD server which is implemented on C this never happens. It seems like a Node.js issue. Notice also that I'm running my StatsD service on virtual box. Is there any issue with Node.js and virtual boxes? (and UDP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a StatsD contributer, the metrics rate which was tested and measured was between 15,000 - 20,000 metrics per sec.
Thats quite good enough and it is what I was looking for.

You can see more details about it in the issue I've opened at StatsD's github project:
https://github.com/etsy/statsd/issues/249